# What are the individual elements within the outcome of a sample space called?

Tags: probability, sampling, random-variable, terminology, sample

What is each entry in an outcome of a sample space called?

For example, say our outcome is ${HHT}$, describing two heads and one tail.

What is each head ($H$) and tail ($T$) member of the outcome called?

Comment: There have been many terminologies adopted over the years: realizations of the experiment (by Kolmogorov), outcomes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are outcomes of each individual toss.

Comment: Sometimes one liner is enough said.